# How to use Values after retrieving data with firebase in swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase

so far I have always worked with the data i am retrieving from firebase without having to do something with them besides showing.
Now I would actually need to store the data in another array and/ or also in general I really wonder how to actually work with the data.

My approach right now looks like this but its actually not working.

Does anyone know how to do it?

```
....

class ProjectCharacterViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    
// MARK: - Properties

    var soloJobs: [String] = []

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        getJobs(for: User.current) { (memberJob) in
            self.uniqueJobs = memberJob
        }
        
    }

...

 func getJobs(for user: User, completion: @escaping ([MemberJobsStruct]) -> Void) {
        
         var jobs: [String] = []

         let ref = Database.database().reference().child("team").child(user.uid)
        
                 ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { snapshot in

                    for case let child as DataSnapshot in snapshot.children {
                    guard let value = child.value as? [String: Any] else {
                        return completion ([])
                        
                }
                        let memberJob = value["memberJob"] as! String
                        jobs.append(memberJob)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                   self.tableView.reloadData()
                               }
                    }
                 })
            soloJobs = jobs
           }
```

Comment: I'm not really understanding your question. What is it that it is not working? Is it the append function to your "jobs" array?

Comment: Sorry! No actually that's working but here for example I would like to make an array ````soloJobs````out of ````jobs````but no matter which different possibilities I try to use, ````soloJobs```` always stays an empty array. Maybe that made my question clearer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `observe` function is an asynchronous call, your `soloJobs = jobs` is getting called before it. That is why it is returning an empty array, because, at that time, your `jobs` array is also empty. Consider calling it inside your for loop as so:

```
func getJobs(for user: User, completion: @escaping ([MemberJobsStruct]) -> Void) {
    
    var jobs: [String] = []

    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("team").child(user.uid)
    
    ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { snapshot in

        for case let child as DataSnapshot in snapshot.children {

            guard let value = child.value as? [String: Any] else {
                    
                return completion ([])      
            }

            let memberJob = value["memberJob"] as! String
            jobs.append(memberJob)
            self.soloJobs = jobs

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
}
```